# What's a pattern for displaying calculated values on a list of components in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an app with tabs. The first three tabs contain input data which is retrieved from the database. From those 3 tabs I calculate 4 other tabs with different metrics I like to see. The last tab implements a  3rd party websocket as well for calculations that require live data.

A company is an input prop for all tab components, then once the different calcs are made, I'm sharing them with services/observables like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) // restricts service to 1 instance only
export class DataService {
  private data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  currentData = this.data.asObservable();

  private cagrs = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  currentCagrs = this.cagrs.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setData(data: any[]) {
    this.data.next(data);
  }

  setCagrs(cagrs: any[]) {
    this.cagrs.next(cagrs);
  }
}
```

So each time I click a company I can navigate to each of the tabs and all the data is loaded, all working just fine:
[image: data component]

The problem I'm having is I'd like some of those calculated values to be pulled into an aggregate list for comparison:

[image: list component]

I've thought about saving the calculations (outside of the valuation ones) to the db, but that seems to violate normalization and I'm not sure it's correct.

I've also thought about just recreating what I've done on all the separate components in the list component but that seems ridiculously redundant.

Is there a way to share data from multiple instances (don't even know if that's the correct term) of component data into a list like this? Do I need to refactor how I'm doing this currently?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Observable by combining other Observables. For example, you could do a combineLatest([]) to combine the two you've shown in your example (or however many you need).

```
  private data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  currentData$ = this.data.asObservable();

  private cagrs = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  currentCagrs$ = this.cagrs.asObservable();

  aggregate$ = combineLatest([
          currentData$,
          currentCagrs$
  ]).pipe(...)
```

You could then pipe through a set of operations to perform any accumulations or other calculations.

Comment: I'm actually doing that in a few of the tabs. But how would I share all the companies at once? The observables now only update 1 company (the one I click) on

Comment: Seems like you'd need another Observable that gets all companies? Then if you are always going to get all companies you could potentially improve performance by "finding" the selected company in the Observable of all companies instead of regetting the selected company.

Comment: so when I click the list page, it gets all the companies (with the input data) through my api, but without the calcs - those are only computed when viewing a single company - maybe I don't understand observables well enough, but are you saying to just do all of the calcs for each company when I pull the list? that's essentially the redundant code I mentioned (moving the calcs from the individual tabs to the list), but if that's the only way I'll do that

Comment: Without knowing the exact requirements and the current implementation, it's difficult to provide detailed suggestions. You *could* get all of the companies right away if you need all of them. You could delay performing the calculations until you need them. You could also "store" the calculation results for the selected company in your local data structures so you don't have to recalculate each time a company is selected.

Comment: I have a set of RxJS videos in a YT playlist if you want to get some additional knowledge/ideas about RxJS patterns: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLErOmyzRKOCrtHaQk-qiq3YhhD_J7K9rA

Comment: currently the calculations i need for the list page are housed in the last tab for an individual company - the calculations for that tab are also dependent upon other calcs in previous tabs - I think I'm talking myself into just getting all the companies calcs up front on the list page and then pushing the individual calcs to their relevant pages - I just kinda started off backwards lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254445/discussion-between-jameseg-and-deborahk).